# Resource qualifiers on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Do Windows Phone 8.1 applications support resource qualifiers, e.g. scales?
Do these qualifiers differ from ones in Windows Store apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Image scaling is supported in windows phone 8.1 RT. Here is how:

[image: Ye]

```
 <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="wpimages/resolution.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```