# Windows Phone 8.1 image resolution converter is not called even though the converter has been added

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 application which loads different images based on the resolution (scale factor).

I have added the reference at the top

```
xmlns:converters="using:MyApp.Converters"
```

I have added the converter in the static resources of the page

```
<converters:ResolutionConverter x:Key="resolutionLogoConverter"
                                    HD720p="/Assets/Logo/About.logo-WXGA.png"
                                    WXGA="/Assets/Logo/About.logo-WXGA.png"
                                    WVGA="/Assets/Logo/About.logo-WVGA.png" />
```

I have added the image in my page. However the converter never gets called and there will be nothing loaded on the page in the place where the image is supposed to load.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource resolutionLogoConverter}}"
           Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

Here's my converter

```
public class ResolutionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object HD720p { get; set; }

    public object WXGA { get; set; }

    public object WVGA { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        switch (ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution)
        {
            case ResolutionHelper.Resolutions.HD720p:
                return HD720p;
            case ResolutionHelper.Resolutions.WVGA:
                return WVGA;
            case ResolutionHelper.Resolutions.WXGA:
                return WXGA;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported resolution type");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in the first line of the Convert function, it is not hitting the breakpoint. Am I doing something wrong. I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not need to use converter for this case. As now in windows phone 8.1 universal app image different images for different resolution is handled by the OS. and also OS will download only the required resolution image on the device(instead of all images) What you have to is to name images differently... see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186061/resource-qualifiers-on-windows-phone-8-1/24189051#24189051)

Comment: Awesome.
I can also name my images as "logo.scale-100.png" "logo.scale-140.png" and get the same behavior right? There is no need to create the folder structure as you have pointed out to your other answer.

Comment: yes, the result will be same, but if app contains many images than it is best to use different folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is not the converter, maybe your `Binding` is not properly set, because I see that you are not binding to a property path (although it's not mandatory). If you are not familiar with the Binding markup extension, you can  check [Binding markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758283.aspx) or [Data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx).

Also, you might try something like:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource resolutionLogoConverter}}"
           Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

and in code-behind:

```
this.myImage.DataContext = ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution;
```

and change in your converter `switch (ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution)` with `switch ((ResolutionHelper.Resolution)object)`